# importing and maping an array of JSON objs in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, json

I am trying to map through the followin array:

```
{

"videos_json": [

  {

    "id": "Student 1",

    "video": "VIDEO TO BE PLAYED",

    "title": "first class",

    "material": "lesson one material",

    "description": "this will be your first lesson"

  },

  {

    "id": "Student 1",

    "video": "VIDEO TO BE PLAYED",

    "title": "22",

    "material": "Information Technology",

    "description": "123"

  },

  {

    "id": "Student 1",

    "video": "VIDEO TO BE PLAYED",

    "title": "22",

    "material": "Information Technology",

    "description": "123"

  }

]
```

}

I have used the following code

```
  import './videos_css.css';
import VideosJSON from '../../assets/mock.json';

function Videos(){
    

    return(
            {VideosJSON.videos_json.map((item, key) => (
                <div className='videos'>
                    <div className='videos_play' key={key}> {item.video}</div>
                    <div className='videos_info'>
                        <h1 className='videos_info_title'> {item.title}</h1>
                        <h2 className='videos_info_material'>{item.material}</h2>
                        <p className='videos_info_description'> {item.description}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ))}
            
        
    )

}

export default Videos
```

But I get this problem

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: C:\Users\adjar\Desktop\JS\lobo_em_ingles\lobo_em_ingles\src\components\videos\videos_index.jsx: Unexpected token, expected "," (8:23)

6 |
7 |     return(

> 8 |             {VideosJSON.videos_json.map((item, key) => (
> |                        ^
> 9 |

Does anyone have any idea why it is "expecting" a ","?

Comment: Try put console.log() in VideosJSON variable

Comment: `return ({` followed by some expression isn't valid JSX.

Answer (score 0):

this error happens because react read this code isn't rendered as a jsx component
you need to wrap this code by a div, so react will read it as a jsx component

```js
  import './videos_css.css';
import VideosJSON from '../../assets/mock.json';

function Videos(){
    

    return(
    <div>
            {VideosJSON.videos_json.map((item, key) => (
                <div className='videos'>
                    <div className='videos_play' key={key}> {item.video}</div>
                    <div className='videos_info'>
                        <h1 className='videos_info_title'> {item.title}</h1>
                        <h2 className='videos_info_material'>{item.material}</h2>
                        <p className='videos_info_description'> {item.description}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ))}
     </div>  
    )

}

export default Videos
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use a valid tag with your data, like if you want to render images use  tag in the map.
I suggest you do the same with the video, but first check it's type.
Try to console.log() the data